# get the latest joomla version numer programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, joomla, version

I am working on a maintenance function which I want to get the latest version numbers(as strings) of all the popular CMS and store them into database.

I've done the wordpress part by send a HEAD request to "http://wordpress.org/latest" and get the versioin number string "3.8.1" from the filename "wordpress-3.8.1.tar.gz".

Now I am wondering how could I deal with Joomla, or if possible, magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

For Long Term Support (LTS) branch -( Recommended) Stable release

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml
```

Short term support (STS) branch

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/sts/list_sts.xml
```

Testing versions.

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/test/list_test.xml
```

All these XML files have link to their details zip files.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

The official way of programmatically getting the latest Joomla version number (for each major version of the CMS) should be through their Joomla! Downloads API:

https://downloads.joomla.org/api-docs/

https://downloads.joomla.org/api/v1/latest/cms