# get the latest magento version numer programmatically

Tags: magento

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594027/get-the-latest-joomla-version-numer-programmatically) yesterday and quickly got an excellent answer. So I move forward to Magento. Could anyone who are export of Magento tell me where I could get the latest version number. (Specifically I need Magento Community Edition's version number)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: So to get the current Magento installation's version number, use the following:

```
$mage = new Mage;
$version = $mage->getVersion();
echo $version;
```

To get the latest available version from Magento themselves, if you download the official "Downloader" version [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and look at line 408 you'll see this:

```
public function download()
{
    if(self::DEVELOPMENT_MODE) {
        if(file_exists($this->getDestinationFilePath())) {
            return $this;
        }
    }
    $downloadPackage = self::DOWNLOAD_PACKAGE;
    $downloadFile ='releases.xml';
    $file = $this->downloadFile($downloadPackage . '/' . $downloadFile);

    $releases = simplexml_load_file($file);
    unlink($file);
    $version = $this->getStabilityRelease($releases);

    $downloadFile = sprintf('%s-%s.tgz', $downloadPackage, $version);
    $file = $this->downloadFile($downloadPackage . '/' . $version . '/' . $downloadFile);

    copy($file, $this->getDestinationFilePath());
    unlink($file);

    return $this;
}
```

...which I guess could give you some idea of how to grab the latest release version number from them. However, that's a bit more complex than I'm able for, but hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I mean the latest version from the official release, not the latest version of my magento website.